# Streaming AAC audio in an Android application

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, aac, internet-radio

I am trying to program a simple Android app that will stream an internet radio station (I have the url), but the stream is aac audio. I am aware of COREaac, but there isn't alot of documentation about it. Is there a separate decoding library I need to get this app to work? Any suggestions would be helpful or if anyone has had a similar issue and resolved it.

Thanks

Comment: You may also try this: [Progressive Custom Audio Streaming](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what you need is here:

[AACPlayer - android](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be what I'm looking for. You wouldn't happen to know where I could find any additional documentation/info?

Comment: You don't need any documentation, everythink is in source code. Just browse it, it's simple to understand ;)

Comment: I am using this code but there is a slight problem. I am playing audio using OpenCore Decoder, it sometime does not play music. This is happening randomly. When stream plays, it is smooth.

Comment: The OpenCore Decoder mentioned in the link works really well albeit two issues.

1 The licensing issue involved in decoding AAC, apparently its patented so exercise caution. This is also mentioned in the library link
2 The stream is decoded during runtime. So this puts a heavy burden on the device. Some devices such as the HTC Evo will soft restart after 1/2 hour of usage.