# How to stream MP4 and AAC format files on android over RTSP

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, aac

I want to build an app which can stream content from a Wowza v 3.5.2 server with following info file container format : mp4 and audio codec :AAC. Both type of files are to be streamed filename.aac and filename.mp4

I have been searching for the last few days and trying out different solutions on the internet e.g. 
[Streaming AAC audio in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009204/streaming-aac-audio-in-an-android-application)

http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

and i have been getting exceptions like
ERROR MediaPlayer Error (1,-2147483648)
ERROR MediaPlayer Error (1,-1)

aacdecoder error

ERROR   Decoder start() failed - ADTS sync word not found

ERROR   AACPlayer   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start native decoder

ERROR   AACPlayer   java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: rtsp

I know there are many many links available discussing this issue, but I have not been able to play the required audio files form a remote server yet.

I need to develop this app for Android 2.2

And Play an AAC and MP4 file formats over RTSP protocol

Need help

Comment: Do you have a sample URL?

Answer (score 1):

VitamioBundle helped me achieve the above. http://www.vitamio.org/en/

Although I have not tested it on many devices, but it works on my Samsung GT-S5830

Comment: dagger would you please up your code or describe how you achieve this.i am searching for long time to solve this issue.